# Java OutputStreamWriter and ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java

Why does the first example print the string 12345 but the second one doesn't?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        baos.write("12345".getBytes());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String output = baos.toString();
    System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(baos);

    try {
        osw.write("12345");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String output = baos.toString();
    System.out.println(output);
    }
```

Am I not using the OutputStreamWriter for its correct use?

Thanks

Comment: add a `osw.flush()` after write

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flush the stream in the second example because `OutputStreamWriter` uses a buffer internally.

It is mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

```
osw.flush();
```

Comment: It was a late night and I couldn't see the wood for the trees.
I found that ows.close() solved the issue for me.
Thanks for the answer though, I will award the points as this also solves my issue.